# How to copy format and formulas only - No values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a problem with my VBA Code. When I used `PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas` in my code it copied everything including values. But I want only is the Formats, Width, and Formula.

This is my code:

```
wb.Sheets("Sheet-T0").UsedRange
wb.Sheets(shtArr(i)).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
wb.Sheets(shtArr(i)).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
wb.Sheets(shtArr(i)).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

In code lines 2 and 3, Yes it's working it copied the cell color, font style, and the width.
But not the height of the cells and the number formats it's still stored as text.

[image: Must Copy]

This is the format of the sheet that I need to copy.
But when I run the code the output something like this.

[image: Output]

The format of the dates, numbers, and height is not okay.

But when I insert the code line 4 which is `wb.Sheets(shtArr(i)).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas` It's just copy everything including the values.

Comment: `xlPasteFormulas` does not copy the values, it copies the formulas only. However, if a copied cell only contains a value (no calculations), that value will act as their formula. So, you might have the impression that it's pasting a value. Do the copied cells actually contain formulas?

Comment: @DecimalTurn, Yes! I had a cell that contain a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `wb.Sheets(shtArr(i)).Range("A1").PasteSpecialxlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats`. The point which @DecimalTurn made i.e. 'in absence of formula, cell value will be copied' also needs to be given a look at.

In addition, to copy & paste Row Height, refer below link [To pass Source range & Target range into a function which in turn does the work of adjusting row height].

https://www.exceltip.com/cells-ranges-rows-and-columns-in-vba/copy-row-heights-and-column-widths-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html